# How to index document files in NAS storage?

Tags: windows, sql-server, indexing, indexing-service

I'm currently developing an application that have to index document files (`.pdf` and `.doc`) which are in NAS storage. After that I want to query them over the application. My customer does not want to upload these files somewhere else.

Can Sql Server or Windows Search Service index these files so I can query them? Or is there any other solution for this type of problem. I think that it should be an easy problem because many people should be doing this.

Comment: I'm also interested in this, although my app development has halted lately to other projects. A quick google brought [this](http://www.mnogosearch.org/), and they *just* released a new version after several years it looks like.

Comment: What about [yacy](http://yacy.net)?